# Can the nomination preview have the same width as the real nomination?

Tags: bug, status-completed, nominations, markdown-preview

When editing posts, I always try to get a good form which improves readability.

However, the preview box of the nomination **has a different width** compared to the nomination itself...

Eg. This results in links that I thought were in the middle, actually are at the borders; making them split.

Comment: @Arjan: Thank you, the 'n' is next to the 's' on my keyboard lay-out. :-(

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: It's still different by one word getting split to the next line. But it's a big improvement, so thanks... :-)

Comment: I should have mentioned after the next deployment (tonight).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The election preview will have a larger width to more closely match the actual text presented during the nomination phase.  Please keep in mind that when the primary and election phases begin the election text will shrink to accommodate the voting controls.